# Joomla! VirtueMart - Unable to make changes locally

Tags: joomla, xampp, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, virtuemart

I'm using Joomla! 1.5.14 and VirtueMart 1.1.3

My codes are hosted on my website. But now that i wanna make changes, i put the codes into XAMPP so that i can run them locally and test it out first before i put them up into the internet.
The problem is, after i logged in as administrator (http://localhost/mysite/administrator/), whenever i click on any links (example: "Manage user fields", "Edit store", etc..), it redirects me to my live site.
If i edit from there, the changes will be made straightaway on my site (which i don't want to).

May i know which files and what are the codes that i should change so that when i click on the links that i want to make changes, it will still be in localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your configuration file in

   ```
   administrator/com_virtuemart/virtuemart.cfg.php
   ```
2. Change the live-site URL from localhost to your live one.